# Adding images to a page with JavaScript that also uses a lazy load type feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to add the BBB and McAfee logos to our checkout page using a bit of JavaScript into the Billing and Payment section. I've written a line of code that works, however, it only works if you refresh the page. Since all activity happens within a single page and the page is reloaded each time you hit continue, I'm not sure why what I wrote isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#payment h3").prepend('<style>#trustIcons1{position:absolute;right:0;top:-5px;}</style><div id="trustIcons1"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0567/6137/files/bbb-secure-trust.png?17807" alt="" class="fl" /><img class="mfes-trustmark mfes-trustmark-hover" border="0" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0567/6137/files/mcafee-secure-trust.png?17807" title="McAfee SECURE sites help keep you safe from identity theft, credit card fraud, spyware, spam, viruses and online scams" alt="McAfee SECURE sites help keep you safe from identity theft, credit card fraud, spyware, spam, viruses and online scams" oncontextmenu="alert(\'Copying Prohibited by Law - McAfee Secure is a Trademark of McAfee, Inc.\'); return false;"></div>');
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#payment h3").prepend('<style>#trustIcons1{position:absolute;right:0;top:-5px;}</style><div id="trustIcons1"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0567/6137/files/bbb-secure-trust.png?17807" alt="" class="fl" /><img class="mfes-trustmark mfes-trustmark-hover" border="0" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0567/6137/files/mcafee-secure-trust.png?17807"></div>');
    })();
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to prepend html or style or both (now you prepend a string)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#payment h3").prepend('<div id="trusticons">your other css</div>'); })(); 

$(document).ready(function(){ $("#payment h3").prepend('<style>your css</style>'); })();

$(document).ready(function(){ $("#payment h3").prepend('<style>your css</style><div id="trusticons">your other css</div>'); })();
```

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#payment h3").prepend('<style>#trustIcons1{position:absolute;right:0;top:-5px;}</style><d‌​iv id="trustIcons1"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0567/6137/files/bbb-secure-trust.png?17807" alt="" class="fl" /><img class="mfes-trustmark mfes-trustmark-hover" border="0" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0567/6137/files/mcafee-secure-trust.png?17807">‌​</div>'); })(); </script>

Comment: That is what I'm using right now that isn't working. I'm not sure why the code pasted like that in my question.